# Find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \int_{x}^{ x^{2}} \frac{1}{\ln(t)}\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Find:
$$
 \lim_{x \rightarrow 1}  \int_{x}^{ x^{2}}   \frac{1}{\ln(t)}\,\mathrm dt 
$$

My calculations lead to 1, but as far as I know, this is not correct result.

Comment: Can you show the calculations?

Comment: Substitute $t=e^y$ and see what happens

Comment: Using the substitution $u = \log t$, I guess that the limit is $\log 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting $x=e^u$, then $t=e^s$, we have to compute:
$$ \lim_{u\to 0}\int_{e^u}^{e^{2u}}\frac{dt}{\log t}=\lim_{u\to 0}\int_{u}^{2u}\frac{e^{s}}{s}\,ds =\lim_{u\to 0}\int_{u}^{2u}\frac{1+s+o(s)}{s}\,ds=\color{red}{\log 2}.$$

Comment: Is it possible to use Mean value theorem to solve this without substitutions?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk: oh, sure, it is pretty much the same.